# Why is SQLiteOpenHelper recreating my existing database?

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to push a database to the emulator. I created the database with a script on my desktop computer, it looks the same as the database created by my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass:

```
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
insert into android_metadata values('en_US');

CREATE TABLE notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement,
                    key text,
                    content text not null,
                    modifydate text,
                    createdate text,
                    syncnum integer,
                    version integer,
                    minversion integer,
                    sharekey text,
                    publishkey text,
                    deleted integer not null default 0,
                    pinned integer not null default 0,
                    unread integer not null default 0);
CREATE TABLE tags (_id integer primary key autoincrement,
                   name text not null, 
                   pos integer not null,
                   noteid integer not null,
                   foreign key(noteid) references notes (_id));
```

But for some reason the app tries to recreate the database even though it already exists. It fails when it tries to create a table that already exists in the database. Maybe someone here knows why?

Comment: Get rid of the `android_metadata` lines and see if that helps. That is not your table, so you should leave it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It turns out that I need to set the version on the database to the same version that my code expects. This is done in my sqlite script like so:

```
PRAGMA user_version = 1;
```